# Bootstrap 3: Alignment of Close Icon

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Close Icon is acting weird.

**Code**

```
<div class="well sidebar-nav">

            <ul class="list-unstyled">
              <li>File Uploaded</li>
              <li><a href="#">File 1</a> <button type="button" class="close" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button></li>
              <li><a href="#">File 2</a> <button type="button" class="close" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button></li>
              <li><a href="#">File 3</a> <button type="button" class="close" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
```

It's appearing like this:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The image is 21px tall, but the `li` is only 20px tall (due to the font) so the floats overlap.  A simple and unobtrusive fix is simply to set the `li` height to 21px.

http://jsfiddle.net/pxHZ9/

You could also `clear` after the `li`s

http://jsfiddle.net/pxHZ9/1/

Answer (score 0):

You must float to the left the both elements:

```
.list-unstyled li a,
.list-unstyled li button { float:left; }
```

------------------------------------------------ or

You can float the first element to the left and the second to the right

```
.list-unstyled li a { float:left: }
.list-unstyled li button { float:right; }
```

after that you must clear the float like this:

```
 .list-unstyled li { zoom:1; position:relative }
 .list-unstyled li:after { content:""; display:table; clear:both; }
```